# Sonar and NUnit project configuration

Tags: c#, tdd, nunit, sonarqube, gallio

I'm configuring Sonar against a .net Solution.

This solution consists in several WCF Services, and each have a separate *.nunit project file.
I need this configuration because most of the services rely on custom configuration sections that I don't want to mock.

Everything work well from the NUnit test application but Sonar doesn't take the *.nunit project files and all tests fail.

How can I tell Sonar (Gallio) to use the NUnit configuration files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it...

Instead of having a single *.nunit project file I need to have a *.config file per tests assembly.

This way the configuration will be always loaded.